# Error in Simple User Define function related to data conversion in R

Tags: r, function

The purpose of this very simple function is just to transform a date column to a date variable and a numeric time (hourly) column to a factor variable, which will be used with plyr later in the code.
I can get this code to run successfully in the command line, but when I attempt to run it in the function I get an error.

```
 # setting up some fake data
    set.seed(31)
    foo <- function(myHour, myDate){
    rlnorm(1, meanlog=0,sdlog=1)*(myHour) + (150*myDate) 
     }
    Hour <- 1:24
    Day <-1:1080
    dates <-seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "day", length.out= 1080)
    myData <- expand.grid( Day, Hour)
    names(myData) <- c("Date","Hour")

    myData$Adspend <- apply(myData, 1, function(x) foo(x[2], x[1]))
    myData$Date <-dates

    myData$Demand <-(rnorm(1,mean = 0, sd=1)+.75*myData$Adspend)
    ############################################################# 

    myData

# Function Creation
    AddCal <-function(DF,Date,Time) {

    DF$Date<-as.Date(DF$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")#Change Date variable into a date type         

    DF$Time<-factor(DF$Time,levels=`c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)) 

    }
#Test Function
    Bob<-AddCal(myData,Date,Hour)
#Error I receive
    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Time", value = integer(0)) : 
    replacement has 0 rows, data has 25920
```

I spent about 2 hours searching for answers and trying different things. Because I can run the individual lines of code at the command line and get the desired result, I am assuming this is an advanced coding problem beyond my novice capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function, replace all instances `DF$Time`  with `DF[[Time]]`  same for `DF$Date`.
Also see the two comments below from @Dwin & @mrip:

- Make sure to return a value
- Make sure to pass string arguments where strings are expected

---

### What's going on:

When you use `DF$Time`, `R` is looking for a column named `Time` in `DF`.  It is *not* treating `Time` as the string variable that you expect.

`DF[[Time]]` on the other hand does treat `Time` as a variable.

The reason the error only refers to `Time` and not `Date` is because Date is both the name of your variable and the name of a column in `DF`.   (If in your function call you would have used something like `AddCal(.. Date=Demand)` or whatever other column name, you would not get back the results you would expect)

#### Side Note:

`c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)`

is equivalent to 
`seq(24)`  and to `1:24`

Comment: Also need to `return(DF)`.

Comment: Ah, so that's what's going on.  I was pretty confused.  In this case the function call should be `Bob<-AddCal(myData,"Date","Hour")`.

Comment: Thank you Dwin and Ricardo much appreciated